# Java - Apache CXF Load WSDL From Jar

Tags: java, resources, load, cxf

I am using Apache CXF to connect to a SOAP API. I've saved the WSDL in my Eclipse project and I want to load this. My project looks like this:

```
src
gen
resources +
          META-INF +
                   myWSDL.wsdl
```

I can load the WSDL if I hard code in the path from the root of my drive:

```
static {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("file:/home/peter/workspace/project/resources/META-INF/myWSDL.wsdl");
        System.out.println(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       //blah
    }
}
```

However, if I try to load the WSDL as a resource it fails:

```
static {
    URL url = null;
    try {
                    url = MyServiceClass.class.getResource("/resource/META-INF/BFExchangeService.wsdl");

        System.out.println(url); //prints null
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       //blah
    }
}
```

How do I load the WSDL from within my project (and, eventually, my .jar)?

Cheers,

Pete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Class.getResource` loads a file from the *classpath*, so you're on the right track.

So, store your wsdl somewhere on your classpath, e.g. your source folder, and treat the source folder as the root of the 'filesystem' e.g. `getResource("/myWSDL.wsdl")`

HTH